# How can get the object in thymeleaf select option?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jquery-select2, spring-roo

Here in autocomplete I get the Product name as expected.

I  want to do some calculation based on the product selected. But in **doCalculation** function i'm getting `id` instead of 'price'. So calculation not working as expected.

Suppose if i change `String idExpression = "#{price}";` then calculation works as expected but Order not saved. Since getting error as below

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.myapp.domain.Product] for property product; nested exception is 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.OneToOne 
 @io.springlets.format.EntityFormat com.myapp.domain.Product] for value 2500; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parsers are not allowed to return null: io.springlets.format.EntityParser@2201ba1c
```

So I want to get the price for calculation at the same time the save feature should not be broken. For now either 1st or 2nd is working for me.

**ProductsCollectionThymeleafController.java**

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, name = "select2", value = "/s2")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Select2DataSupport<Product>> select2(GlobalSearch search, Pageable pageable,
        Locale locale) {
    Page<Product> products = getProductService().findAll(search, pageable);
    String idExpression = "#{id}";
    Select2DataSupport<Product> select2Data =
            new Select2DataWithConversion<Product>(products, idExpression, getConversionService());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(select2Data);
}
```

**OrderCollectionThymeleafController.java**

```
@PostMapping(name = "create")
public ModelAndView create(@Valid @ModelAttribute Order order, BindingResult result,
        Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        populateForm(model);
        return new ModelAndView("/order/create");
    }

    Order newOrder = getOrderService().save(order);
    UriComponents showURI = getItemLink().to(OrderItemThymeleafLinkFactory.SHOW)
            .with("order", newOrder.getId()).toUri();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + showURI.toUriString());
}
```

**orderview.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal validate" method="POST" data-th-object="${order}" data-th-action="@{${collectionLink.to('create').with('order', order.id)}}">
    <fieldset id="containerFields">
        <div class="form-group has-error has-feedback" data-z="3c00987d" id="servicio-product-field" data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('product')}? 'has-error has-feedback'" data-th-class="form-group" data-th-with="collectionLink=${@linkBuilder.of('ProductsCollectionThymeleafController')}">
            <label for="product" class="col-md-3 control-label" data-th-text="#{label_servicio_product}">Product</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Select2 -->
                <select data-th-field="*{product}" onChange="doCalculation()" class="form-control dropdown-select-ajax" data-allow-clear="true" data-data-ajax--url="${collectionLink.to('select2')}" data-ajax--cache="true" data-ajax--delay="250" data-ajax--data-type="json" data-data-placeholder="#{info_select_an_option}">
                    <option data-th-unless="*{product} == null" data-th-value="*{product.id}" data-th-text="*{{product}}" selected="selected">Product</option>
                </select>
                <span data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('product')}? 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" data-th-if="${#fields.hasErrors('product')}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span id="product-error" class="help-block" data-th-if="${#fields.hasErrors('product')}" data-th-errors="*{product}">Error message.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function doCalculation() {
                var price = document.getElementById("product").value;
                alert("price: " + price);
                // Do some calculation
            }
            doCalculation();
        </script>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Product.java**

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@RooEquals(isJpaEntity = true)
@Entity
@EntityFormat
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String productName;

    @Min(1L)
    @NumberFormat
    private Integer price;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EntityFormat
    private Order order;

    public static final String ITERABLE_TO_ADD_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE = "The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!";

    public static final String ITERABLE_TO_REMOVE_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE = "The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!";

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return this.productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order= order;
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@RooEquals(isJpaEntity = true)
@Entity
@EntityFormat
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.MERGE,
        javax.persistence.CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")
    @RooJpaRelation(type = JpaRelationType.AGGREGATION)
    @EntityFormat
    private Product product;

    public static final String ITERABLE_TO_ADD_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE = "The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!";

    public static final String ITERABLE_TO_REMOVE_CANT_BE_NULL_MESSAGE = "The given Iterable of items to add can't be null!";

    /**
    * This `equals` implementation is specific for JPA entities and uses the
    * entity identifier for it, following the article in
    * https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/06/06/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
    *
    * @param obj
    * @return Boolean
    */
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        // instanceof is false if the instance is null
        if (!(obj instanceof Order)) {
            return false;
        }
        return getId() != null && Objects.equals(getId(), ((Order) obj).getId());
    }

    /**
    * This `hashCode` implementation is specific for JPA entities and uses a
    * fixed `int` value to be able to identify the entity in collections after
    * a new id is assigned to the entity, following the article in
    * https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/06/06/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
    *
    * @return Integer
    */
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public void addToProduct(Product product) {
        if (product == null) {
            removeFromProduct();
        } else {
            this.product = product;
            product.setOrder(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeFromProduct() {
        if (this.product != null) {
            product.setOrder(null);
        }
        this.product = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `Select2DataWithConversion` data type only returns the identifier that will be set as `value` attribute of the `option` element and the representation of the object (in your case the product name) as the `text` attribute of the `option` element.

That is the minimum info that the select2 component needs to be constructed.

https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

However, as you described in your answer, it's really common to need more info in your Select2 component. For that reason, we overloaded the constructor of `Select2DataWithConversion` including a boolean parameter to return the entire information of the object.

Check this overloaded constructor here:

https://github.com/DISID/springlets/blob/master/springlets-data/springlets-data-commons/src/main/java/io/springlets/data/web/select2/Select2DataWithConversion.java#L76

So, you just need to change your **ProductsCollectionThymeleafController.java** to use it like:

```
Select2DataSupport<Product> select2Data = new Select2DataWithConversion<Product>(products, idExpression, getConversionService(), true);
```

Now that yor select2 component is going to receive extra information, you need to store it in a `data-*` attribute of your select2 option during the option creation. To do that use the `templateSelection` function that offers the select2 component.

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections#using-a-jquery-selector

Now, your `doCalculation` should obtain the selected option and after that, the `data-price` attribute.

```
   <script>
    function doCalculation() {
     var price = $('#product').find(':selected').data('price');
     alert("price: " + price);
     //Do some calculation                   
    }
    doCalculation();
   </script>
```

And that's all!

**EDIT**: I've just create the following project where you could find your desired behaviour: https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/tree/master/select2-with-extra-info
Just check the necessary changes in the following commit: https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/commit/105c18f7ad0da4d1e2089fbf71d4f27ccdb60689

Hope it helps,

Comment: Getting undefined for price value

Comment: Since could not find data in this $('#accomidation').find(':selected') . Added console.log(price); and found this

Comment: How are you implementing `templateSelection` select2 function?

Comment: I've just created a sample project using Spring Roo where you could find the solution. https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/tree/master/select2-with-extra-info Just check the commit where I've applied the necessary changes. https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/commit/105c18f7ad0da4d1e2089fbf71d4f27ccdb60689